# How to check and select the first working link?

Tags: python, http

The site that I want to parse is often unavailable. Fortunately, it has several mirrors that may not be available either. Therefore, I need to check them all and select the first available mirror for further work. How can i do this?

```
import requests

for url in ['URL1', 'URL2', 'URL3']:
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print ('Works!')
    else:
        print ('Does not work...')
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `break` to end `for loop` if you got active `url`.

```
import requests
urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']

def do_something(page):
    #do operation on page.
    print(page.text)

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        print (f"{url} is Working!")
        do_something(response)
        break

    else:
        print (f"{url} is down")
```

here `for loop` will continue until it run out of `urls` or it encounter active `url`.
after finding first active `url` it will call `do_something()` and `break` the `for loop`.

hope it will help.